# Separate source dependencies from user and userdebug configuration

Tags: android, git, github, repo

Where i live there isn't optical fiber, so before downloading android source i edit manifest.xml for deleting unused projects consequently i have less data to download.

Reading [AOSP Documentation](https://source.android.com/source/building.html)

Here's explain the difference from userdebug, user and eng

I'm interested for user configuration.

My question: Is it possible delete projects from manifest.xml that user configuration does not use?

Sorry in advance my english!

Comment: you can use Local Manifests to delete projects, please see the [Local Manifests] section of [manifest-format document](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt) for more details.

Comment: @gzh I'm already using the local manifest

Answer (score 0):

AOSP Project (Android Project) is a set of projects (Google use a ***gerrit*** and ***repo command***), these projects can be a android applications (APKs), a java applications (JARs) and other types of projects. For example:

- packages/apps/Settings (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/) is a android application for change the settings of the device.
- framework/opt/telephony (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/)
  is a java application (jar) with the internal functionally of the
  device (calls, sims, message)

You can delete the project that you want to delete, but this can make that the device don't work correctly.

What project do you want delete?

Comment: Thanks @Victor Santoja for your answer. For example i have hundreds of <project path="external/..." name="platform/external/...." groups="pdk" / <project path="external/aac" ........... />
  <project path="external/android-clat" ..........." />
  <project path="external/android-mock" ............." />
  <project path="external/androidplot".............. />
  <project path="external/antlr" .........................." />
  <project path="external/apache-commons-math" ............" />
 and so on. Are all necessary?

Comment: What device are you using?